# Validate Xml in Flex3 Air

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, xsd, air

I am opening  xml in air application . i need to validate opening xml(Xml need to have specific  node), for this some of them telling there is XSD validation on vb and .net , but i need to know, likewise any validation tool is available in Air ?.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

These blog posts might be of use.

[XML & XSD 1](http://blog.misprintt.net/?p=181)

[XML & XSD 2](http://blog.misprintt.net/?p=192)